# how to check items of a checkboxlist based on some data using jquery

Tags: jquery, struts2, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist as

```
        <s:checkboxlist list="{'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','fri','Sat','Sun'}" 
                             name="modProcessVO.weeklyCal" id="days"/>
```

the object

```
  " modProcessVO.weeklyCal" 

   have data as  tue,fri,sat
```

My problem is that I am unable to check the checkbox of items of s:checkboxlist based on the data from the server.(that is" modProcessVO.weeklyCal")...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following option.

```
name="modProcessVO.weeklyCal"
```

and make sure that the "weeklyCal" should be **string[]**

Comment: not String , It should be String array.Still you have problem, update your question little bit clear...